React: Array inside of State is undefined when accessed from callback
I have a callback function, that is supposed to edit a value in an array, that is inside of a State. When I try to access the dataZähler, so the array itself, I get unedefined/Array of length 0 back. Why is that?
Code in Question(hopefully reduced to its bare necessities):
'use client'
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ProtokollEintrag, TogglePosition, ZählerCallback, ZählerObjekt } from "./dataTypes";
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup, Divider, ZoomProps } from "@mui/material";
import ElectricalServicesIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ElectricalServices';
import clsx from "clsx";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { CreateCounterPopUp, CreateEntryPopUp, EditCounterPopUp, EditEntryPopUp, CalculateDeltaPopUp } from "./pages/myPopups";

export default function Home() {
  //data and internal logic states, table-content, which rows are selected, is the data still loading, etc.
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataZähler, setDataZähler] = useState<ZählerObjekt[]>([]);
  const [dataProtokoll, setDataProtokoll] = useState<ProtokollEintrag[]>([]);
  const [selectedRowZähler, setSelectedRowZähler] = useState(-1);
  const [selectedRowProtokoll, setSelectedRowProtokoll] = useState(-1);
  //View-Logic states, which table is shown, if modals should be seen, etc
  const [showEditZählerModal, setShowEditZählerModal] = useState(false);

  //on start, load both csv's into states
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/loadCsv')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setDataZähler(data.dataZähler)
        setDataProtokoll(data.DataProtokoll)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, []);

  function handleEditZähler() {
    if (currentTable === TogglePosition.Zähler && selectedRowZähler >= 0) {
      setShowEditZählerModal(true);
    }
  };

  const handleEditZählerCallback: ZählerCallback = useCallback((data: ZählerObjekt | null) => {
    console.log(dataZähler);
    if (data) {
      const oldData = dataZähler.map((elem, idx) => {
        if (idx === selectedRowZähler)
          return { ...data };
        return elem;
      });
      console.log(data);
      console.log(oldData);
      setDataZähler(oldData);
      setSelectedRowZähler(-1);
    }
    setShowEditZählerModal(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      {/* Buttons und Toggle zur Verwendung und Steuerung des Interfaces */}
      <div className="justify-center flex sticky bottom-0 space-x-4 bg-[white] bg-opacity-60">
      <button onClick={handleEditZähler} disabled={selectedRowZähler < 0} className={clsx("bg-[#0ea5e9] border-[none] text-[white] text-center inline-block text-base rounded-[5px] px-5 py-3 my-2", { "bg-[#d1d5db]": selectedRowZähler < 0 })}>Bearbeiten</button>
      </div>
      {/*Modal Div - all edit/Cancel/Save/Create/Delete modals go here*/}
      <div>
        <Modal size="lg" show={showEditZählerModal} onHide={() => setShowEditZählerModal(false)}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>
              Zähler Bearbeiten:
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <EditCounterPopUp data={dataZähler[selectedRowZähler]} callback={handleEditZählerCallback} />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

and if it is important, here is the Modal for Editing the ZählerObjekt:
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { ZählerObjekt, ProtokollEintrag, ZählerCallback, EintragCallback } from "../dataTypes";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { generateGenericObjectID } from "../util/objectIdentifier";

interface CounterProps {
    data: ZählerObjekt,
    callback: ZählerCallback
}

export function EditCounterPopUp({ data, callback }: CounterProps) {
    const [newCounter, setNewCounter] = useState({ ...data });

    function handleSpeichern(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) { //dont forget to set the id of the new object
        event.preventDefault();
        setNewCounter({ ...newCounter, ...{ id: generateGenericObjectID(newCounter) } });
        callback(newCounter);
    }

    function handleInputChange(field: string, event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const newState = { ...newCounter };
        newState[field as keyof ZählerObjekt] = event.target.value;
        setNewCounter(newState);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                {Object.entries(newCounter).slice(1).map((elem, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <Form.Group
                            className="mb-3" key={idx} controlId={elem[0]}
                        >
                            <Form.Label>{elem[0]}</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                as="textarea"
                                rows={2}
                                placeholder={"z.B. " + String(data[elem[0] as keyof ZählerObjekt])}
                                value={elem[1]}
                                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(elem[0], e as any)} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    );
                })}
                <div className="float-right">
                    <button onClick={handleSpeichern} className="bg-[#22c55e] border-[none] text-[white] text-center inline-block text-base rounded-[5px] px-5 py-3 my-2">Speichern</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

Why is dataZähler unedfined in the callback? and how can I fix this?

The issue is an empty dependency array. Include dataZähler and selectedRowZähler in the dependency array of useCallback. Check the code below:
const handleEditZählerCallback: ZählerCallback = useCallback((data: ZählerObjekt | null) => {
  if (data) {
    const oldData = dataZähler.map((elem, idx) => {
      if (idx === selectedRowZähler)
        return { ...data };
      return elem;
    });
    setDataZähler(oldData);
    setSelectedRowZähler(-1);
  }
  setShowEditZählerModal(false);
}, [dataZähler, selectedRowZähler]);

The dependencies array [dataZähler, selectedRowZähler] ensures that the callback has the most recent values of these dependencies every time they change. Without this, the callback may use stale values of dataZähler and selectedRowZähler.

Its pretty late, i'll try it tomorrow and get back to you with results.

Nvm, got excited, tried it and it works, thank you :)
